# Post action not working in form inside bootstrap popover

Tags: html, django, twitter-bootstrap-3, popover

I am trying to save a url from an input field(form is inside bootstrap popover)but nothing happens when I click save button.
This is my html code:

```
<div id="popover-content" class="hide">

<form name ="bform" method = "post" action = "{% url 'savebookmark' %}" class ="form-inline">
 {% csrf_token %}
  <div class="form-group">
  <input placeholder = "http://..." name = "url" class = "form-control" type = "text">
  <button type = "button" class = "btn btn-danger">Save</button>
  </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

**views.py**

```
def save_bookmark(request):

bmark = request.POST.get("url")
user = user
obj = UserBookmark(user_id=user,bookmark=bmark)
obj.save()
return HttpResponse("Data saved")
```

**urls.py**

```
 urlpatterns = [
 url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
url(r'^register/$',views.register, name='register'),
url(r'^login/$',views.login_view, name='login'),
url(r'^register/success/$',views.register_success, name='register_success'),
url(r'^category/$',views.get_category,name='getcategory'),
url(r'^#/$',views.save_bookmark,name='savebookmark'),
]
```

Please guide me on what am I doing wrong in this?

Answer (score 1):

the form doesnt work because you havent used a SUBMIT button to submit the form

```
<div id="popover-content" class="hide">

<form name ="bform" method = "post" action = "{% url 'savebookmark' %}" class ="form-inline">
 {% csrf_token %}
  <div class="form-group">
  <input placeholder = "http://..." name = "url" class = "form-control" type = "text">
  <button type = "submit" class = "btn btn-danger">Save</button>
  </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

use this, hope it will work as you need

Comment: Oh yes.That was quite silly on my part.Thanks:) It worked